# Given two vectors of ints, determine whether one vector is a prefix of the other

Tags: c++, vectors, iteration

Given two vectors of ints, write a program to determine whether one vector is a prefix of the other.

- For vectors of unequal length, compare the number of elements of the smaller vector.
- For example, given the vectors containing 0, 1, 1, 2, and 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, respectively, your program should return true.

---

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    const std::vector<int> ivec1 = { 0, 1, 1, 2 };
    const std::vector<int> ivec2 = { 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8 };

    const decltype(ivec1.size()) size = ivec1.size() < ivec2.size() ? ivec1.size() : ivec2.size();
    const std::vector<int>& smallVec = ivec1.size() < ivec2.size() ? ivec1 : ivec2;
    const std::vector<int>& bigVec = smallVec == ivec1 ? ivec2 : ivec1;

    bool bPrefix = true;
    for(decltype(ivec1.size()) i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        if(smallVec[i] != bigVec[i])
        {
            bPrefix = false;
            break;
        }
    }

    std::cout << "small vector:\n";
    for (const auto i : smallVec)
        std::cout << i << ", ";
    std::cout << "\nIs prefix of big vector:\n";
    for (const auto i : bigVec)
        std::cout << i << ", ";
    std::cout << "\n" << (bPrefix ? "true" : "false") << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: The title is a bit ambiguous. Do you mean that for two vectors you need to figure out which is a prefix, or **if** one is a prefix of the other? If so, do you need to tell which one?

Answer (score 9):

1. Embrace `auto`. Not only is it shorter, but avoids embarrassing bugs in choosing the wrong type.
   `decltype()` is generally much more cumbersome.
2. Embrace abstraction. Solving the task itself deserves its own re-usable function. Good naming even reduces the need for comments, which can get out-of-sync.
3. Embrace the standard library. It is well-tested and well-known. Reinventing wheels for no reason is a poor use of time.
4. You refrained from using `std::endl` until your last line. No need to use it at all, ending the program flushed the output too.
5. `std::boolalpha` is the tool of choice for streaming a `bool` as `"true"` or `"false"`.
6. Combine `std::copy()` and `std::ostream_iterator` for streaming an iterator-range.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

template <class T, class U>
constexpr bool is_shorter_prefix(const T& a, const U& b) noexcept {
    const auto n = std::min(std::size(a), std::size(b));
    return std::equal(std::begin(a), std::begin(a) + n, std::begin(b));
}

template <class T>
void output_range(std::ostream& os, const T& t) {
    using U = decltype(*std::begin(t));
    std::copy(std::begin(t), std::end(t), std::ostream_iterator<U>(os, ", "));
}

int main() {
    const std::vector<int> a = { 0, 1, 1, 2 };
    const std::vector<int> b = { 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8 };

    const auto is_prefix = is_shorter_prefix(a, b);

    std::cout << "small vector:\n";
    output_range(std::cout, a.size() <= b.size() ? a : b);
    std::cout << "\nIs prefix of big vector:\n";
    output_range(std::cout, a.size() > b.size() ? a : b);
    std::cout << "\n" << std::boolalpha << is_prefix << "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 6):

The review from user673679 is good and covers most of the important points.  If you have a C++20 compiler, you can get even better compiler optimizations using `std::ranges`.  Here's an example:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>
#include <ranges>

int main()
{
    constexpr std::array<int, 4> vec1{ 0, 1, 1, 2 };
    constexpr std::array<int, 7> vec2{ 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8 };
    constexpr auto minsize = std::min(vec1.size(), vec2.size());
    constexpr auto result{std::ranges::equal(vec1 | std::views::take(minsize),
                                             vec2 | std::views::take(minsize))};

#if PRINT_RESULTS
    std::cout << "vec1 = { ";
    std::copy(vec1.begin(), vec1.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>{std::cout, ", "});
    std::cout << "}\nvec2 = { ";
    std::copy(vec2.begin(), vec2.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>{std::cout, ", "});
    std::cout << "}\nisPrefix = " << std::boolalpha << result << '\n';
#else
    return result;
#endif
}
```

[Try it live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4bc819538d9e36d7) on CoLiRu.

Even more fun is that because everything is `constexpr` here, all of the calculation is done at compile time.  Here is [an example](https://godbolt.org/z/raGEqcMfE) that shows that the `main` above that simply returns the result is literally two machine language instructions!

Comment: You could also use `std::ranges::copy`.

Answer (score 5):

```
const decltype(ivec1.size()) size = ivec1.size() < ivec2.size() ? ivec1.size() : ivec2.size();
```

Could just be:

```
const auto size = std::min(ivec1.size(), ivec2.size());
```

---

```
const std::vector<int>& bigVec = smallVec == ivec1 ? ivec2 : ivec1;
```

`operator==` for `std::vector` doesn't compare the reference, it checks that the contents of the two vectors are the same. (i.e. it checks the length, then iterates through every element). This isn't what we want.

---

We can use the `<algorithm>` header to do this task more easily:

For example [`std::equal`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/equal):

```
auto const size = std::min(ivec1.size(), ivec2.size());
auto const is_prefix = std::equal(ivec1.begin(), ivec1.begin() + size, ivec2.begin(), ivec2.begin() + size);
```

or [`std::mismatch`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/mismatch):

```
auto const mismatch = std::mismatch(ivec1.begin(), ivec1.end(), ivec2.begin(), ivec2.end());
auto const is_prefix = (mismatch.first == ivec1.end() || mismatch.second == ivec2.end());
```

(Note that before C++14, we would have to ensure that the first sequence passed to `std::mismatch` was shorter than the second. Afterwards, it doesn't matter).

Comment: Yes - `std::mismatch` is the tool for this job.  No need to even look at the size.

Answer (score 2):

The problem statement in the question says

> - For example, given the vectors containing `0, 1, 1, 2` and `0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8` respectively, your program should return true.

The implication is that your program should *return false* if neither vector is a prefix of the other.  In C++, we do that by returning `EXIT_FAILURE`, or indeed any non-zero value.

The simplest means to achieve that is to add

```
return !bPrefix;
```

at the end of `main()`.